# Craft Commerce starting order ids form a higher number?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there a easy way to start Craft Commerce order ids form a higher number?
So the can follow on from an old system and not overlap?

autoincrement in the DB table maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [Craft plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that listens to the [onBeforeOrderComplete](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onbeforeordercomplete) event and implement whatever sort of order number format your business requirements require.

Alternatively here's an existing plugin that uses that method that might already cover your needs: https://github.com/bossanova808/CommerceFriendlyOrderNumbers

Comment: Sorry Brad just to check is there no way to just skip the the ID of craft_commerce_orders DB table on to for example 2000 as a starting point?

Comment: @Green17 the order ID is not incremental. It is the next Craft element ID. Elements in Craft are entries, categories, products, orders etc. So there is no way to make `order.id` incremental. Best using a custom field with the plugin brad mentioned.

Comment: @Green17 my plugin (above) will do exactly what you want - you can start at 2000 (or any number) and you'll get consecutive numbers from them on.  We're about to clear the first 1000 orders with it (starting at ~25000 from our old cart) - so pretty confident it works well at this point.  It's pretty easy to implement but if you get stuck find me on slack and I'll help you out.

Comment: Thanks so much for all you help, I will use you plugin Jeremy.

Comment: @JeremyDaalder your plugin worked great thanks so much for your and Brads help.